# Two same stock Samsung phones, different apps?

Tags: applications, samsung

So, I got to install two Samsung Galaxy S8+; then should have been refurbished and wiped, and flashed with stock firmware.

One of them did not have the latest OS update (via Settings/Software Update) - I updated that, now then both show the same (Current version: G955FXXUCDUD1/... strings are the same)

What irritates me to no end, is that these two devices, that should otherwise be identical, show different default stock apps installed. Noticed this before trying Google Play update - and the situation is the same after the Google Play update (done without logging in - via the three dots menu in upper left corner on start screen).

Exclusive to one phone are (via comparing Settings/Apps list):

- Briefing
- Smart Switch

... and exclusive to the other phone are:

- (Google) Drive
- Duo
- Google Play Movies & TV
- (Google) Photos
- upday

How is this possible, and why does this occur?

Again, note that I'm talking about both being refurbished, flashed with stock ROM, no root, and presumably no "manual" installing of apps...

Could Samsung have "pushed" these apps, depending on if these phones were originally sold through a carrier?!

(I just noticed now, that in Settings/About phone/Software information, all data is identical for both phones, except for "Service Provider SW ver.", one of which is SAOMC_SM-G955F_OXM_ROM_PP_0014, and the other is SAOMC_SM-G955F_OXM_NEE_PP_0015 ... I guess this has something to do with it - but what is it?).

Comment: You should boot into recovery mode. There the phones should display details information about their software and state.

Comment: It depends on how you did the initial setup, you have confirmed some dialog for installing that apps automatically on only one of your phones. you can double check these are user apps, not system apps